# Error message "{responseCode8,responseMessageERROR_INVALID_PAYMENTTOKEN}" is displayed when I call the API for verifying the purchase token

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-iap

I made a request to verify the purchase token by referring to the official materials, but error message "{responseCode 8 , responseMessage ERROR_INVALID_PAYMENTTOKEN}" was returned. The URL of the request API was {rootUrl}/applications/purchases/tokens/verify. Is there anyone who can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that consuming or confirming a product is performed for a user only when the user has successfully purchased it, that is already owned the product.

Then you also need to ensure that the input parameters in the API call request are correct.
For example,use the wrong site to check that purchaseToken.or The productID is not added to the PMS or is incorrect. and so on.

For more details,you can refer to [error codes](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/server-error-code-0000001050166248-V5).